# php cURL get back posted values from the url that I posted my data

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

Consider that I post my data to a payment gateway to process my payment. Then the payment gateway post me back some data to my receipt URL.

My URL: https://myurl.com/payment
PaymentGateway URL : https://paymentgateway.com/postdata
My Receipt URL: https://myurl.com/receipt

I tried to do this procedure using PHP CURL. So I created a piece of code to post my data to payment gateway's URL and able to process a payment. But I couldnt able to read the post data that the payment gateway provider post me back. I am sure there will be a function in cURL to read the post data that the other server is sending me.

Is it possible? Can anyone please give me that function to read all the post data that the other server is sending me?

Hope this is not confusing. Please ask me if you need more explanation.

Thank you,

Karthik

Comment: Is there not any docs for your payment gateway.

Comment: Yes it is avalible but they want me to redirect to their URL with the post data to process and they will redirect me back to my url with the post data. But I want to keep my users in my domain. Thank you Lawrence

Comment: The area your having problems with is reading the data sent back from the gateway, right? this would be after payment so reading the docs regarding that would not affect any domain redirect. Just point the post to your receipt controller, store the post in a text file or the database, then compare or look for words like `verified` matching your order ids.

Comment: The problem with doing it this way is that you are in contact with your users' credit card data, and you might be storing it.  If your payment gateway has any kind of merchant website certification process your code will fail.  That is why they want you to redirect the user to their gateway url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a POST request, you give your cURL object an associative array of the values you're submitting; so, access the values then.

If you need to persist them, maybe put them in $_SESSION which can then be retrieved on subsequent page requests.

Comment: Thank you Cinqo. But it only prints the page content but not the post data that it sends me....

Comment: @Karthik - When you make the cURL request, you have to give it an array of the post values, correct? Therefore, you already have them...

Comment: ya... but the server gives me back even more post values along with the one i sent... i dont know to read those. I thought I could read the post values if not its alright i will find another way...